# Find the number that the studio should purchase to maximize profits

Tags: inequality

> *A studio sells photographs and prints. It costs $€$ $20$  to purchase each photograph and it takes  $ 2 $ hours to frame it. It costs $€$ $25$  to purchase each print and it takes $ 5 $ hours to frame it. The store has at most $€$  $400$ to spend and at most $ 60 $ hours to frame. The studio makes $€$ $30$ on each photograph and $€$ $50$ profit on each print.*
>
> Find the number that the studio should purchase to maximize profits.

I need to know the system of inequalities to model the problem on my graphing calculator so I can find the point of intersects.

How would I go about doing that?

I thought my way of calculating it was corrected, but my teacher told me to recheck it so now I don't trust my answers anymore. If someone could verify that would be great!

**Edit: This was the system of inequalities I came up with:**

> $20x+25y<=400, 2x+5y<=60, X>=0, Y>=0$
>
> The points of intersects I got were:
>
> - 0,5
> - 0,16
> - 20,0
>
> And finally the profit equation is:
>
> $P=30x+50y$

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sorry, see my edit :-)

Comment: A simple approach is to find a solution that uses up one resource, either the framing hours or the investment.  Then see if you can do more of one  maintaining the full usage of the limited one, trading off the other and increase profits.  This is a description of how the simplex method works in a simple case.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for your reply! I did indeed use the Simplex Method and came up with the system in my main question, but I need to know if it's correct. Last time I did this, my teacher asked me to recheck it, so I don't trust my answers anymore.

Comment: Your equations look good to me.  Why didn't you show them before?  You seem to have answered the question you asked originally.  Where are you stuck solving the problem?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for letting me know! I am still unsure if the points of intersect are correct, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes making a graph helps clarify things.  Can you make out the feasible region and its corners from the picture here?
[image]